# Writing the exact same thing in CSV file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping

I've encountered an issue with my writing CSV program for a web-scraping project.

I got a data formatted like this :

```
table = {
    "UR": url,
    "DC": desc,
    "PR": price,
    "PU": picture,
    "SN": seller_name,
    "SU": seller_url
}
```

Which I get from a loop that analyze a html page and return me this table.
Basically, this table is ok, it changes every time I've done a loop.

The thing now, is when I want to write every table I get from that loop into my  CSV file, it is just gonna write the same thing over and over again.
The only element written is the first one I get with my loop and write it about 10 millions times instead of about 45 times (articles per page)

I tried to do it vanilla with the library 'csv' and then with pandas.

So here's my loop :

```
if os.path.isfile(file_path) is False:
    open(file_path, 'a').close()
file = open(file_path, "a", encoding = "utf-8")

i = 1
while True:
    final_url = website + brand_formatted + "+handbags/?p=" + str(i)
    request = requests.get(final_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "html.parser")
    articles = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "dui-card searchresultitem"})
    for article in articles:
        table = scrap_it(article)
        write_to_csv(table, file)
    if i == nb_page:
        break
    i += 1
file.close()
```

and here my method to write into a csv file :

```
def write_to_csv(table, file):
import csv

writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = " ")
writer.writerow(table["UR"])
writer.writerow(table["DC"])
writer.writerow(table["PR"])
writer.writerow(table["PU"])
writer.writerow(table["SN"])
writer.writerow(table["SU"])
```

I'm pretty new on writing CSV files and Python in general but I can't find why this isn't working. I've followed many guide and got more or less the same code for writing csv file.

edit: Here's an output in an img of my csv file

[image]

you can see that every element is exactly the same, even if my table change

EDIT: I fixed my problems by making a file for each article I scrap. That's a lot of files but apparently it is fine for my project.

Comment: share the error ?

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: I would think that the function `writer.writerow` is meant for writing a row, not a single field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be solution you wanted

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['UR', 'DC', 'PR', 'PU', 'SN', 'SU']    

def write_to_csv(table, file):
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow(table)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: That wasn't that but I give  you an upvote because it's well better formatted than mine ! Thanks !